# Method or data member not found.

Tags: vba, excel

when debug it will shows - method or data member not found and will highlight at .cell. may i know why with that error?

i already change the cells to cell. but still did not work.

i am stil new in VBA, i already searched a few website or any suggestion, but still its hard for me to understand and not really clear.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'dimention the variable
Dim DataSH As Worksheet
Dim Addme As Range
Dim str As String
Dim totalRows As Long

'set the variable
Set DataSH = Sheet1
'error handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:
'set variable for the destination
Set Addme = DataSH.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Me.txtName = "" Or Me.cboAmount = "" Or Me.cboCeti = "" Then
MsgBox "There is insufficient data, Please return and add the needed information"
Exit Sub
End If
'determine worksheet row to post data
totalRows = Sheet1**.Cell**(Rows, Count, "A").End(xUp).Row
If totalRows < 3 Then
totalRows = 3
Else
totalRows = totalRows
End If
'send the values to the database
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 1) = txtName.Text
If cbWhatsapp.Value = True Then
str = "Whatsapp, "
End If
If cbSMS.Value = True Then
str = str & "SMS, "
End If
If cbEmail.Value = True Then
str = str & "Email, "
End If
If cbFacebook.Value = True Then
str = str & "Facebook, "
End If
If cbPhoneCall.Value = True Then
str = str & "Phone Call, "
'deleting comma and space, the 2 characters at the end of str
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 2) = str
If optYes.Value = True Then
Sheet1.Cell(totalRow + 1, 3) = "Yes"
ElseIf optNo.Value = True Then
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 3) = "No"
End If
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 4) = cboAmount.Value
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 5) = cboCeti.Value
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 6) = txtPhone.Text
Sheet1.Cell(totalRows + 1, 7) = txtEmail.Text
'sort the data by "cboCeti"
DataSH.Select
With DataSH
.Range("A2:G10000").Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess
End With
```

Comment: Two things: **1)** If you are using the code sheet name and you are referring to Sheet1 then you can write `totalRows = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xUp).Row` **2)** Since you are new to VBA you probably aren't using the code sheet name, so try `totalRows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row` Notice how I fully qualified each object to its parent.

Comment: Orait, thankyou Scott. Ill try to follow your suggestion :)

Comment: Think you need to replace all `.cell()` with `.cells()` (note the `s`). Ctrl+H or Edit menu may let you do this more efficiently/exhaustively. I would definitely consider Scott Holtzman's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of your code
2. Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of your code
3. You are not fully qualifying your objects. Use the variable `ws` as seen in code to properly qualify your objects
4. You are using `Cell` when you should be using `Cells`
5. You had some typos where you used `totalRow` instead of `totalRows`
6. Properly indenting your code goes a long way. Namely with readability, making your code easier to update in future, **and making your code easier to de-bug** since it is easier to follow

`Option Explicit` would have caught errors 4 and 5 and brought them right to your attention by highlighting the undeclared (typo) variables and other compile errors.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Addme As Range, str As String, totalRows As Long

Set Addme = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Me.txtName = "" Or Me.cboAmount = "" Or Me.cboCeti = "" Then
    MsgBox "There is insufficient data, Please return and add the needed information"
    Exit Sub
End If

totalRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
totalRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(totalRows, 3)

ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 1) = txtName.Text

If cbWhatsapp.Value = True Then
    str = "Whatsapp, "
End If

If cbSMS.Value = True Then
    str = str & "SMS, "
End If

If cbEmail.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Email, "
End If

If cbFacebook.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Facebook, "
End If

If cbPhoneCall.Value = True Then
    str = str & "Phone Call, "
End If

str = Left(str, Len(str) - 2)
    ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 2) = str

If optYes.Value = True Then
    ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 3) = "Yes"
ElseIf optNo.Value = True Then
    ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 3) = "No"
End If

ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 4) = cboAmount.Value
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 5) = cboCeti.Value
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 6) = txtPhone.Text
ws.Cells(totalRows + 1, 7) = txtEmail.TextG1

ws.Range("A2:G10000").Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

End Sub
```